# Unable to see the full UIScreens using XIB in iOS

Tags: ios

I have an existing project which developed an Xcode 5. At that time we used .xib files now i am trying to add few more functionalities to this app. Currently i am using Xcode 7.2. But i am unable to see the full screens. I did like: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J060.png) and
[Click here to view(xib) in Xcode Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVA3J.png)
Here i want to display all screens should be full screen

How can i overcome this issue?

Comment: please take a screenshot of your nib file in IB with attribute inspector

Comment: I uploded here check it out once

Answer (score 0):

show us some code ,so we can figure out the problem.
if you are adding this as subview you can try this

```
let myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewidentifier", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? YourView


myView.frame = self.view.bounds

self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: I guess the same. Also, @himagiri remember to enable auto-layout before change the frame directly since the UI is implement in IB otherwise it will become totally a mess.